# How Flash is able to compare two textfield ( or any component) variable?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Comparison of number or string is understandable. But how come when in flash AS3.0, we do :

```
var a:TextField = new TextField(); 
var b:TextField = new TextField() ;
.....
.....
.....

if ( a==b)
{
......
}
```

comparison is being done ?

Is their some Application-wide ID, that flash gives to each component instance. Or is it compairson of the strings ( comparing the whole path of each component )

thanks
V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new object of anything, Flash reserves some memory for the place. For example, on my imaginary simplified flash runtime enviroment:

```
var a:Object = new Object();

Memory Dump:
0000: [Object 0]

a = 0000
```

Variables are like a pointer to the memory location.

Now, flash passes objects by reference. For example:

```
function A(){
    var a:Object = new Object();
    var b = a;
}

Memory Dump:
0000: [Object 0]

FunctionA.a = 0000 /*These pointers are scoped to the function that declared it*/
FunctionA.b = 0000
```

**We can prove this with the following example:**

```
var a:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var b = a;
b.graphics.lineStyle(1);
b.graphics.lineTo(100,100);
addChild(a);
```

In this example, a and b are the same thing. Anything done to a will be done to b, because they are the same objects.

However, this does not work for strings, numbers (Number, int, uint), booleans. They are exceptions, and they pass by **value**.

```
function A(){
    var a:String = "Hello world.";
    var b = a + "Hi";
}

Memory Dump:
0000: [String "Hello world."];
0008: [String "Hello world.Hi"];

FunctionA.a = 0000;
FunctionA.b = 0000;
```

To answer your question now, here's what will happen:

```
Memory Dump:
0000: [Object TextField 1]
0016: [Object TextField 2]

FunctionA.a = 0000; //This is var a = new TextField
FunctionA.b = 0016; //This is var b = new TextField
FunctionA.c = 0000; //This is like var c = a;

is the number 0000(a) the same as 0016(b)? No.
is the number 0000(a) the same as 0000(c)? Yes.
```

Now, if you want to see if the text is equal, then:

if(a.text == b.text){

}

This is because a.text is a string, and with strings, flash checks not by address, but by value.

I hope I have not overly complicated the whole thing and you understand why :)

Answer (score 2):

Reference comparison... basically memory locations (number of the memory location the reference points to) is checked if they are the same... somebody else should have the time to give a more meaty answer.

Answer (score -1):

if you're trying to compare the string values. you want to first reference the string with the .text property. (a or b actually reference the field itself, not whats written there)

then you want to search for the string in another string like this:

if(b.text.indexOf(a.text) > 0) trace("the string of b is exactly the same as a);

Comment: `-1` The question is asking about the relationship between two objects, not the values of two properties on each object.